# How to select deeply nested anchor for a click function

Tags: jquery

I have this structure

```
<dd class="treediv">
<ul>

    <li>

      <span class="title">title <a class="serieslink" href="link">HIV/AIDS     project overview;  early program documents; AIDS Prevention Program files</a></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</dd>
```

How can I select the anchor for a click function
 in jquery

Comment: By giving it an `id`?

Comment: just use $('.serieslink').on('click', function(){}); or $('a').on('click', function(){});

Comment: did not work, I have other links outside of the dd with the same class and they are working correclty but not the ones inside the dd and the list

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/ykf830et/ unless you're doing something. can you provide the whole html so that we can see the nested structure?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the appropriate CSS selector to get at it:

```
$( ".serieslink" ).on( "click", function() {
     console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

It depends on if that class "serieslink" is specific enough to get what you want or you can be more specific by giving it an id:

```
<a class="serieslink" href="link" id="myuniqueId">
```

and then get to it by an ID query:

```
$("#myuniqueId")
```

Read about the best ways to do your selectors here:
[JQuery Selectors Page](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

When attaching a click event to an anchor, be sure to prevent the default action of the browser on that element first using the event arg passed into the success function by default.

As @brariden also suggested, try using IDs on your elements for query clarity and flexible markup.

If you absolutely can't use ids and the click event will be shared for all anchors inside of the dd, here is a solution you could use:

```
$('dd.treediv > ul > li > span > a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //custom event handler logic
}
```